# Running apache with admin permissions dangerous?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, dropbox

I am trying to get my apache server (OS X Lion, not server edition) to run, using a folder inside Dropbox as DocumentRoot. This works fine, as long as I run apache as admin, meaning: with admin permissions. I am sometimes logging into hotspots, so before I do that again I'd like to know if I'm endangering myself; the only things running on the server are files I created.
And 2nd: How can I get apache running with dropbox with no admin account? I tried to chmod 755 the Documents folder inside Dropbox, but it had no effect on apache – though I could see that it had changed permissions when I looked in the Finder.

To clarify:

> My Document Root = .../myuser/Dropbox/.../htdocs

Works with apaches httpd.conf having these ernties:

> User [some admin]
>
> Group admin

What permissions to I have to apply to htdocs to get apache running as _www:_www?

Comment: Ok, here's the deal:

        sudo chown _www:_www /path/to/directory

This makes the apache user (_www) and the web-group, equally named, the directories owner and disables Dropbox or yourself from accessing it using the finder, but:
navigate to the folder, right click on it -> Information -> on the bottom open the lock. Click the + left beneath the list of users, add yourself and make sure you grant yourself the need rights. Click the "gear" and apply to all subdirectories.

But the question still remains: is running apache as amdmin dangerous?

Answer (score 2):

Apache is designed to be run as regular user. In production environments it's normal to [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chroot) software that can't do this.

If you do this only for your own machine, for private use, you're good. In production it's definitely not a good idea.

As for permissions:

try

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www /path/to/dir
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/dir
```

(or, if the OSX `chmod` supports non-octal modes, use this: `sudo chmod -R u+rwX,g+rX,o+rX /path/to/dir`)

Your user will be able to only read the files, he won't be able to delete them though.

Add yourself to `_www` group (under linux it's `gpasswd -a user-name _www`, don't know if it'll work with OSX) and change permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/dir
```

But you may need to adjust the `umask` for apache to `002` to keep those files this way.